# Why is CSS Media Query Not Working On Django?

Tags: python, css, django-templates, media-queries

I'm trying to implement the mobile view of my Django project but the media query part of my CSS seems not to be working in the django project. Given that I made a div container to display flex, with flex-direction of column when the screen size is 375px or less, the div continues displaying as row which is the display pattern given for the larger screens.

### Index.html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Oppapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        
    {% for object in object_list %}
    
    <div class="postlist">
        
        <div class="listicon">
            <img src="{{object.image.url}}">
        </div>
        <div class="listtext">
        <ol><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{object.title}}</a></ol>
        <ol>{{object.article | truncatewords:15| linebreaks}}</ol>
        <ol>{{object.location}}</ol>
        <ol><small>{{object.created}}</small></ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% comment %} <hr> {% endcomment %}
    {% empty %}
    <p>No News Here</p>

    {% endfor %}
        
</div>

    {% endblock content %}
   
    
</body>
</html>
```

*style.css static file*

```
.postlist{
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsl(208, 11%, 55%);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsl(208, 11%, 55%);
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.listicon{
    display: flex;
    flex: 16%;
}
.listicon img{
    display: flex;
    flex: 20%;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
}
.listtext{
    flex: 70%;
 
}





@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
    .postlist{
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsl(208, 11%, 55%);
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsl(208, 11%, 55%);
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .listicon img{
        display: flex;
        flex: 20%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .listtext{
        display: flex;
        flex: 70%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

### Settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = 'DEBUG'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'django_social_share',
    'oppapp'
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oppject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'oppject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases


# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'dbname',
        'USER':'user',
        'PASSWORD':'*****',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'OPTIONS': {  
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"  
        }  
    }
}
# db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
# DATABASES['default'] = db_from_env

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Lagos'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'oppapp/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Media URL and ROOT added by me

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are the static files showing in the browser source?

Comment: Yes they're showing, but the media query part is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the media query was not working as I did not include a 'head' tag in the base.html file which was extended in the index.html file. So I added the below html code in the base.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Oppapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
```